# Angular Django CSRF integration

Tags: angularjs, django

[image]I have a separate angular app and Django application running on different localhost ports with CORS enabled. My angular app sends its post requests to Django service endpoints to receive JSON response. I have attached the screenshot of angular project structure below. I need to know where I should integrate Django's CSRF token in my angular app assuming that I have one of my post request in **Django.service.ts** and what is the best practice that I need to follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing the JSON data from the API shouldn't require a CSRF token to complete, check your views and make sure they aren't requiring it.

Comment: Thank you. But what if for instance, we wanted to post form data that does not have any json response from the server. Can you brief the procedure for that?

Comment: You'll need to set the cookie. Make a get request to the API before posting

Comment: Thank you, I know that. Can you brief me the procedure of adding csrf token to my request header such that Django detects it?

Comment: Angular code to send a request to server: `let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    let body = JSON.stringify(data);
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/predictor/', body, options);` and in my index.html I have included the following: `<script>
     var my_app = angular.module('app', [/* dependencies */]).config(function($httpProvider) {
      $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
      $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
     });
  </script>`